# Angular 4 code splitting in angular-cli

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-2

I am using angular-cli to build my project(ng build --prod). 
I have 3 problems in my production build:

1. Rendering blocking style-sheet(74 kb)
2. Huge `vendor.bundle.js` (1.1 MB)
3. Big `main.bundle.js` (398 kb after using lazy loading for each component)

I want to load my site very fast on 2G connection. When i tested it on lighthouse the first meaningful page is 7 secs.
Then i converted my project from angular cli to webpack (`ng eject --force`). Then `vendor.bundle.js`  size became 5.9 mb.

I want to split my `vendor.bundle.js` and remove blocking style-sheet using angular-cli.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to use splitchunk from webpack

have a look at this article:

https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-split-your-chunks-with-webpack-f8a9df5b7758

Answer (score -1):

Try to create your build with `--aot` it will reduce the size of your `vendor.bundle.js`. Also enable gzip compression on your server.

`--aot` Ahead-Of-Time compilation also have some great befits. Always try to create your build with it.

Comment: --aot is inbuilt in  angular 4. When you do --prod it will compile your code with aot

Comment: and gzip compression is also enabled on the server. I want to split vendor js.

Comment: @kartikajas you can use this [gzip link](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html) to get more understating about it.